# Why does my Perl sub receive the parameters of its parent?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, parameters

Here is my test code :

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use Array::Utils qw[array_minus];

sub sub1 {
    my @array1 = qw(1 2 3);
    my @array2 = qw(1 3 5);
    my @arrayMinus = array_minus(@array1, @array2);
    my @sortedArrayMinus = sort @arrayMinus;
    print "Result from array_minus + sort : " . join(",", @sortedArrayMinus) . "\n";
    my @sortedArrayMinus2 = sort array_minus(@array1, @array2);
    print "Result from sort array_minus : " . join(",", @sortedArrayMinus2) . "\n";
}

sub1("a","b");
```

When I run it, it gives the following result :

```
Result from array_minus + sort : 2
Can't use string ("b") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at Array/Utils.pm line 123.
```

So, the second call to array_minus fails because of wrong parameters.

I'm using version 0.5 of the Array::Utils library (I've manually copied it from http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ZMIJ/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm)
The relevant lines of this file are :

```
sub array_minus(\@\@) {
    my %e = map{ $_ => undef } @{$_[1]};
    return grep( ! exists( $e{$_} ), @{$_[0]} ); 
}
```

If I debug the value of @_ in array_minus, its value is OK for the first call, but it's [ 'a', 'b' ] for the second call.

So it behaves as if array_minus sub receives the parameters of sub1, instead of the ones I passed, but only when I also ask to sort the result on the same line. What's wrong in my code?
I'm using Perl 5.22.1.

Comment: You are initializing arrays that seem to contain only numbers using strings. Not necessarily wrong *per se* but odd. Also, plain sort will use string comparisons not numeric so `@x = (11, 1, 7)` will sort as `1, 11, 7` -- which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the warning in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) and fix the syntax:

```
my @sortedArrayMinus2 = sort(array_minus(@array1, @array2));
```

The original syntax was telling `sort` to use `array_minus` as the comparison function.

Comment: Left unsaid is the fact that `sort` by itself will use string comparisons even though the arrays seem to contain numbers which, for some reason, are initialized as strings.

Answer (score 9):

This expression:

```
sort array_minus(@array1, @array2)
```

really means "sort the list resulting from concatenating `@array1` and `@array2`, using `array_minus` as the comparison function".

As explained in [`perldoc -f sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

> Warning: syntactical care is required when sorting the list returned from a function. If you want to sort the list returned by the function call `find_records(@key)`, you can use:
>
> ```
>     my @contact = sort { $a cmp $b } find_records @key;
>     my @contact = sort +find_records(@key);
>     my @contact = sort &find_records(@key);
>     my @contact = sort(find_records(@key));
> ```

... because otherwise you're hitting the `sort SUBNAME LIST` syntax (which exists for historical reasons: perl had `sort` long before it supported subroutine references).